# Подмена сетевого адреса на 127.0.0.1

Tags: linux, сеть, localhost

Есть две написанные мною программы для linux, которые общаются по сети. При запуске их на различных устройствах можно отследить трафик между ними через tcpdump. Когда же я запускаю их на одном компьютере, то вместо того, чтобы общаться через заданный мною интерфейс весь трафик перенаправляется на loopback, можно ли как-то отключить подобную оптимизацию?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3130925/10138734

Comment: @Akina, трафик на lo я вижу. Вопрос, как раз, заключается в том, как сделать так, чтобы трафик остался, например, на eth0, при взаимодействии двух программ по сети на одном устройстве.

Comment: Ну вообще-то скорее всего никак... либо трафик варится внутри IP-стека - что собственно и происходит,- но тогда localhost, либо трафик отправится в сетевой интерфейс и там в кабель - но тогда он уже не вернётся, карта сама от себя не принимает... ну или загоните одну из программ в виртуалку (или обе - в разные виртуалки).

Comment: Если вы используете только один интерфейс, то нет - нельзя отключить. Если несколько и они включены в роутер, то можно с помощью iptables(NAT) или namespaces, назначив на них разные ip-адреса. А вообще лучше использовать какие-нибудь виртуалки - это даст 100% результат, но потребует ресурсов.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте на существующий интерфейс ещё один адрес:

```
ifconfig <интерфейс>  add <IP-адрес>
```

И настройте две Ваши утилитки на работу с этими двумя РАЗНЫМИ IP-адресами. По идее, всё должно работать...